# Store Private Keys Wallet

Tags: security, cryptography, storage, private-key, wallet

I'm working at a crypto wallet extension for a startup and currently we are facing the issue of storing private keys after we generate them from a mnemonic phrase. I was thinking about storing those password in the local `localStorage` as an encrypted format using `AES` but this doesn't seems to be good enough.

I was also thinking about using the `chrome.storage` but this one seems to have the same issue of not being secured.

As for the `chrome.filesystem` this one is deprecated.

If anyone has an idea of how we could store private keys safely on the user's machine please let me know.

Comment: Cant you just hash them and Check each Time? You could also check tag from aes if you use supported algorithm.